# How to add item in pagination?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, pagination

i have download JS for Pagination but i donot know how to add item it just show number any one please help.

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<section>
    <div class="data-container"></div>
    <div id="pagination-demo1"></div>   
</section>
</div>
<!-- JS Started -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../src/pagination.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
 (function(name) {
 var container = $('#pagination-' + name);
 var sources = function () {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < 196; i++) {
    result.push(i);
  }
  return result;
}();
var options = {
  dataSource: sources,
  callback: function (response, pagination) {
    window.console && console.log(response, pagination);
 <!-- item cause to show number but i want to know to to put text -->
    var dataHtml = '<ul>';
    $.each(response, function (index, item) {
      dataHtml += '<li>' + item + '</li>';
    });
    dataHtml += '</ul>';
container.prev().html(dataHtml);
  }
};
//$.pagination(container, options);
container.addHook('beforeInit', function () {
  window.console && console.log('beforeInit...');
});
container.pagination(options);
container.addHook('beforePageOnClick', function () {
  window.console && console.log('beforePageOnClick...');
  //return false
});
})('demo1');
 })
</script>
```

[this is result in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5glO.jpg)

as show in to item should be edited in some list reference but only sequence of number shows me, please help me to solve this problem or share me some links with similar pagination( many page numbers but show some).
thanks in advance.